# one button for passing multiple data

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My program should pass the values of **phone number and email recognized from the editText** into the other activity which contains the edittext for phone number and email respectively.
I already managed to pass the value of phone number and email one by one.However i failed when trying to pass them at the same time.

```js
 public void onClickbutton2(View v) 
 {

  /*----------------------------------phone number catcher------------------*/
 
  String text = _field.getText().toString();
  Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\\d{5,11}");
  Matcher m = pt.matcher(text);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  while (m.find()) {
   sb.append(m.group()).append(",");
  }
  String[] phones = sb.toString().split(",");
  Intent i = new Intent(this, Contacts.class);
  i.putExtra("phones", phones);
  startActivity(i);

  /*------------------------------------------------email catcher-----------*/
      
  String email = _field.getText().toString();
  String EMAIL_PATTERN="^.+@.+\\..+$";

  Pattern pp = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
  Matcher e = pp.matcher(email);
  StringBuilder sc = new StringBuilder();
  while (e.find()) {
   sc.append(e.group()).append(",");
  }
  String[] emails = sc.toString().split(",");
  Intent j = new Intent(this, Contacts.class);
  j.putExtra("emails", emails);
  startActivity(j);

 }
```

The above codes are for the recognition of phone number and email from the edittext.The codes below are the intents where the values of phone number and email should be passed into

```js
        Intent phone=getIntent();
        String [] phones = phone.getStringArrayExtra("phones");
        edtTxtContactNumber.setText(phones[0]);

        Intent email=getIntent();
        String [] emails = email.getStringArrayExtra("emails");
        edtTxtContactEmail.setText(emails[0]);
```

So is it possible to pass multiple values when clicking only 1 button?Why do i get nullpointerexception when im trying to pass multiple values at the same time?I think there is something i must do  at startactivity().Any idea?

Comment: Where do you get the nullpointer? How does your code look like, when passing 2 values in one intent?

Comment: you are starting activity twice and you have 2 intents. remove the second one.

Comment: You should put the extra values in a single intent.

Comment: put your extras THEN start your activity. right now you are putting phones in this intent, then you starting it then doing it all again for emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the comments in the following code to understand the change.

```
public void onClickbutton2(View v) 
    {

        /*----------------------------------phone number catcher------------------*/
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Contacts.class);   //<-- Declare your Intent variable here.
        String text = _field.getText().toString();
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\\d{5,11}");
        Matcher m = pt.matcher(text);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (m.find()) {
            sb.append(m.group()).append(",");
        }
        String[] phones = sb.toString().split(",");

        i.putExtra("phones", phones);   //<-- add Phone number to intent

        /*------------------------------------------------email catcher-----------*/

        String email = _field.getText().toString();
        String EMAIL_PATTERN="^.+@.+\\..+$";

        Pattern pp = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher e = pp.matcher(email);
        StringBuilder sc = new StringBuilder();
        while (e.find()) {
            sc.append(e.group()).append(",");
        }
        String[] emails = sc.toString().
        i.putExtra("emails", emails);    //<-- add email to Intent
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

**on another activity**

```
String phoneNumber = getIntent().getStringExtra("phones");
String emaiId = getIntent().getStringExtra("emails");
```

Comment: Thanks man!it worked!my bad didnt realised i declare intent variable multiple times @iSandeep